# Is it a bug in Xamarin StackLayout children.Add, Clear function?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin-studio, stacklayout

When creating a button statically, there is no problem in clearing and adding the stacklayout. However, there is a problem when dynamically creating a button and clearing and adding it.

Is there anything I need to do separately when creating dynamically?
Do I have to create the layout itself in code too?

I don't understand. This is like a bug.

```
<ContentView x:Name="xMainContentsView" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">

            <ScrollView Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
                <StackLayout x:Name="xView" Margin="35,80,35,80" Spacing="25" Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
                    <Button Text="g02" Clicked="Button_Clicked"></Button>                   
                </StackLayout>
            </ScrollView>
            
            <!--<StackLayout x:Name="xPageView"  Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
            </StackLayout>-->
</ContentView>


private void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            xView.Children.Clear();
            xView.Children.Add(new Spectrum(this));
        }




private void InitializeCompView()
        {
              
            foreach (MainViewMeasureType contents in Enum.GetValues(typeof(MainViewMeasureType)))
            {
                CtrlButton button = new CtrlButton
                {
                    WidthRequest = 180,
                    HeightRequest = 180,
                    Text = contents.ToString(),
                    ClassId = contents.ToString(),
                };
                button.Pressed += BtnMainContentClick;

                xView.Children.Add(button);
            } 
        }
        



private void BtnMainContentClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            xView.Children.Clear();
            xView.Children.Add(new Spectrum(this));
        }
```

Comment: You haven’t explained what the problem is.

Comment: You can see the difference in the result when calling the clear() function of stacklayout when making the button dynamic and making it static.

If it is created statically, it proceeds normally without errors.
But if you make it dynamic, it throws an exception.

Comment: What exception does it throw?

Comment: It throws a NotSupportException and is hard to trace back to the call stack.

Answer (score 0):

I have created a sample to test the StackLayout children.Add, Clear function and met the same problem.

In addition, the exception message mentioned the FasterRender and then I disabled it in the mainactivity. But the same exception came, so I change the `button.Pressed += BtnMainContentClick;` to `button.Clicked += BtnMainContentClick;`. It worked well.

So you can also try this and report this as a bug to the xamarin on the github.